# WordPress Custom Query and Pagination

Tags: wordpress

we try to use a custom query to enhance the results of a normal WordPress query. The result of this query may have more results then the normal query.

```
$d = date("Y-m-d");

$new_query = "SELECT t.*, d.* FROM (" . $wp_query->request . ") t
, wp_testzdfdates d WHERE 1=1 AND
( 
   (
    DATE_FORMAT(d.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') >= DATE_FORMAT('".$d."', '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
   )
OR (
    DATE_FORMAT(d.end_date, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') >= DATE_FORMAT('". $d ."', '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
   )
)

AND d.post_id = t.id
ORDER BY
  d.start_date ASC, d.end_date ASC, d.post_id";


$events = $wpdb->get_results($new_query, OBJECT);
```

In this constallation the normal query perhaps returns 4 results and the enhancement returns 19 results.

This means, that I have no chance to go to the page 2, because the query returns just 4 results which makes a secound page obsolete.

Is there any way to change this behavior. I already tried this (http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination) but it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for pagination.

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin